# Override certain CSS property for all MUI components at once

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking to override the value of a certain CSS property 'letter-spacing' for all MUI components in one place. Even when adding the CSS property on the div which encloses the entire app, the MUI components' default value is taking higher priority.